# Google billing library cancelled all subscriptions

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I'm using Google's Billing library to make subscriptions inside my app.

After ~~ 3 days google play has refund every subscription of my users, why did it was?

Some code with activity, which make subscriptions:

```kotlin
    private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null
    private val purchasesUpdateListener = PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
        val isSuccessResult = billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
        val hasPurchases = !purchases.isNullOrEmpty()
        if (isSuccessResult && hasPurchases) {
            purchases?.forEach(::confirmPurchase)
            viewModel.hasSubscription.value = true
        }
    }

    private fun confirmPurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
        val consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
            .build()
        billingClient?.consumeAsync(consumeParams) { billingResult, _ ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                //all done
            }
        }
    }
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdateListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build()

        connectToBillingService()
    }

    private fun connectToBillingService() {
        billingClient?.startConnection(this)
    }

    private fun getPurchases(): List<Purchase> {
        val purchasesResult = billingClient?.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
        return purchasesResult?.purchasesList.orEmpty()
    }

    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(result: BillingResult) {
        if (result.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            updateSkuMap()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using Play Billing Library 2.0 or above. Starting from Play Billing Library 2.0, all purchases must be acknowledged within three days. Failure to properly acknowledge purchases will result in purchases being refunded.
Checking [Play Billing Library v2.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#release-2_0) and [Processing Purchases](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your code, you are using `consumeAsync()` to confirm a purchase,

which is the correct way for **one time consumable product** , because `consumeAsync()` will acknowledge for you automatically.

But for **subscriptions**, you should use `client.acknowledgePurchase()` method rather than `consumeAsync()`

Here is the sample for Kotlin

```
val client: BillingClient = ...
val acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener: AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = ...

suspend fun handlePurchase() {
    if (purchase.purchaseState === PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
            val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
            val ackPurchaseResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
               client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams.build())
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be I am too late to answer, but may be reference for other members.
Yes, refund happens in 3 days, when purchase is not acknowledged. And in this case it seems to be a consumable in-app purchase, where purchase is acknowledged locally. I can see in code, that purchase is getting consumed(acknowledged), but consume might be getting fail in ConsumeResponseListener. I would suggest to consume purchase only when purchase object is in 'PURCHASED' state. Which means to apply a check before going to consume it.

```
purchaseItem.getPurchaseState() == com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED
```